# Changing image on hover using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an arrow icon on an image slider and when I hover over the image I just want the image to change. I currently have been playing around with various jquery but nothing seems to be working. I don't need anything fancy such as fade-outs, just change the image on hover.

HTML

```
<div class="next"><img src="next.png"></div>
<div class="prev"><img src="prev.png"></div>
```

CSS

```
.next img{
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 315px;
right: 570px;
z-index: 99;
}

.prev img{
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
top: 315px;
left: 550px;
z-index: 99;

}
```

Jquery

```
$('.next').hover(function(){
$(this).attr('src','prev.png');
},function(){
 $(this).attr('src', 'next.png'); 
});
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery, image changing on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This without javascript:

```
<div class="next"></div>
<div class="prev"></div>

.next {
  background: url(next.png) no-repeat;
}
.next:hover {
  background: url(prev.png) no-repeat;
}

.prev {
  background: url(prev.png) no-repeat;
}
.prev:hover {
  background: url(next.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Other then keeping it all in css and avoiding jquery, is there any benefit to not using jquery. I'm just wondering for the future?

Comment: of course - CSS is "static" declaration, but not "dynamic" interpreted like js/jquery. Its fastly

Answer (score 1):

`next` is the `div` not the `img` so you need to find the `img` inside the `next` then change its `src`.

```
$('.next').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'prev.png');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'next.png');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v24oq0rr/)

Comment: Aha ))) always find image for new hover event )))