# Giving a Javascript function a id or class

Tags: javascript

im trying to get a img hover into another img on multiple img's.
on 1 img it works like a charm, but now i need the same function for 4 more img's how do i define that?

my current code:

```
        function MouseRollover(MyImage) {
    MyImage.src = "images/massage.jpg";
}
    function MouseOut(MyImage) {
    MyImage.src = "images/wellness.jpg";
}

                <a href='wellness.html'> <img src="images/wellness.jpg"  
            onMouseOver="MouseRollover(this)" 
            onMouseOut="MouseOut(this)" /> </a>
```

Comment: I've changed your [tag:java] tag to a [tag:javascript] tag. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: So do you face some issue If you repeat similar for other images ?

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm kinda new to this! thanks for doing that! i will keep my eyes open next time:)

Comment: kuldeep.kamboj: yea i do when i copy/paste it to the other img's  it also copies the img...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass image source as parameter?

```
function setSrc(MyImage, newSrc) {
    MyImage.src = newSrc;
}
```

```
<a href='wellness.html'>
    <img src="images/wellness.jpg"  
         onMouseOver="setSrc(this, 'images/massage.jpg')" 
         onMouseOut="setSrc(this, 'images/wellness.jpg')" />
</a>
```

Or event better to not pass `wellness` image twice:

```
function setSrc(myImage, newSrc) {
    var original = myImage.src;
    myImage.src = newSrc;
    myImage.onmouseout = function(){ myImage.src = original; }
}
```

```
<a href='wellness.html'>
    <img src="images/wellness.jpg"  
         onMouseOver="setSrc(this, 'images/massage.jpg')" />
</a>
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover) for similar problems and jQuery solutions.

Comment: hmm, i took your code but its not working here.. although i think i know where you wanna go with this, and how it gives all the images their own property. ( I'm new to Javascript)

Comment: The second code works perfectly! Thank you very much! I also took al look at the jQuery solutions.. but to be honest its a bit out of my league for now.. soon i will start learning jQuery^^