# Float image code on the side of website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code here, and I want to float it on the right side of the screen, like next to the scroll bar.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="http://i.imgur.com/JrrRHqr.jpg";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="http://i.imgur.com/Mu27x47.jpg";
// End -->
</script>
<a href="URL HERE" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;" target="_blank">
<img name="image1" src="http://my_button_image" border=0></a>
```

I would like it to keep it's functionality. Also, if possible, please incorporate my question in your answer.

Thanks!

EDIT: I want it to be like this

IMAGE 1

[image]

But with my image code that chaged when you hover over it....

EDIT2: Here's the code I'm using (HTML)

```
<script>
<!-- Begin
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="http://i.imgur.com/JrrRHqr.jpg";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="http://i.imgur.com/Mu27x47.jpg";
// End -->
</script>
<body>
<a href="URL HERE" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;" target="_blank">

  <img name="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/Mu27x47.jpg" id="image1"></a>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  </body>
```

Then CSS

```
 #image1{ 
 position: fixed; 
 top:50px; 
 left: 0; 
 width: 50px; 
 height:50px
 }

 .content { 
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  }
```

Here is an image of what it's doing to my site...

IMAGE

[image]

Comment: are you wanting it to stay fixed next to scrollbars?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.... I just want it on the right side of my website. @Case

Comment: do you want it to scroll with the site or stay in one place

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I would like it to scroll with the page. @Case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it to be fixed, rather than absolute, I assume. So when you scroll your page, your image won't move. If so, try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/4959aeg2/5/
CSS:

```
#image1{ 
  position: fixed; 
  top:50px; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 50px; 
  height:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="URL HERE" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;" target="_blank">

  <img name="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/Mu27x47.jpg" id="image1"/></a>
```

If you want the image to scroll with your page, just change `position: fixed;` to `position: absolute;`

Comment: Now this is what I want.... But when I add the codes, it makes a huge hole in the center of my website? Plus the image switching doesn't work like it does on jsfiggle.

Comment: I don't understand. I would need to have either a visual of what is going on or your code.

Comment: @JonDanker change `img {` to `#image1 { ` in your CSS.  And your `<img>` id should be `id='image1' ` rather than `id='#image1' `

Comment: Sooo, I got the CSS to work, it goes in the corner now like it should, only thing is there's like a grey overlay now, and I can't hover over the image/it's not working.

Comment: So I found that the problem is this code here........ can you fix it?   <img name="image1" src="IMAGE"></a>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  </body>

Comment: `<img` tag is not being closed. Adding `/>` might fix it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was able to fix it by removing a line of code, I posted the fix in my question. Thanks again and God bless.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? [jsfiddle.net/u9s4rh57/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/u9s4rh57/2/) (UPDATED)

.HTML

```
<img src="//i.imgur.com/JrrRHqr.jpg"
data-alt-src="//i.imgur.com/Mu27x47.jpg" class="myImage"/>
```

.CSS

```
.myImage{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

and JS for "swapping" images from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover) from @Cᴏʀʏ

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
  $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
  $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function () {
  $('img.myImage').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

Comment: I updated with the function from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover)
and created a new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9s4rh57/2/) with the images changing and the image right next to the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding you right you can do something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/u6kd4vqc/9/

```
.myclass {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question... I want my code, to be planted on the side of the website, like the image I posted in my question.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I got it to work! Thanks Edmar Miyake and everyone! I had to edit Edmar's code a little to get it to work. Here's what I did. I removed `<div class="content">` in the HTML.

Here's the finished code!

HTML

```
<script>
<!-- Begin
loadImage1 = new Image();
loadImage1.src="SECOND IMAGE";
staticImage1 = new Image();
staticImage1.src="FIRST IMAGE";
// End -->
</script>
<body>
<a href="http://www.allaboutgod.com/how-to-be-saved.htm" onmouseover="image1.src=loadImage1.src;" onmouseout="image1.src=staticImage1.src;" target="_blank">

  <img name="image1" src="FIRST IMAGE" id="image1">
  </div>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
#image1{ 
  position: absolute; 
  top:2500px; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 125px; 
  height:332px;
}

.content { 
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```