# How to create a simple improvement version of "hover and <img> change" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm doing a JavaScript function which is to hover anyone of the `<a>` elements and change the `<img>` src and `<p>` accordingly.

I am practicing and learning JavaScript. So I have create a super simple JavaScript function code.

```
function onHover() {

    var pistiProducts = [
        "https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-1.jpg",
        "https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-2.jpg"
    ];

    var replace = document.getElementById("replacement");
    var itemdec = document.getElementById("text-replacement");

    replace.src = pistiProducts[1];
    itemdec.innerHTML = "Test 1";

}
```

In my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu-wrapper d-flex">                                               
  <div class="dropdown-item-wrapper flex-grow-1">                                                
    <a id="pisti-products" onmouseover="onHover();" class="pisti-products" href="#">Action</a>                                                   
    <a class="" href="#">Another action</a>                                                      
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                 
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-display-wrapper">                                                     
    <div class="display-img replacement">                                                            
     <img id="replacement" class="w-100 img-fluid" src="https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-1.jpg" alt="">                                                       
    </div>                                                       
    <p class="mb-0 w-100 pisti-title" id="text-replacement">Another action</p>                                                   
  </div>                                                 
</div>
```

Currently what I will do is I will write 13 function and set the `onmouseover=""` to the relevant one. But I don't think this is a best solution because I have more to do something like this.

As you can see my JavaScript code included `Array`. But I have no idea what can be done with array. :(

I need help to suggest me the best and easy solution. Please suggest me in JavaScript code instead of jQuery. I'm not good with basic JavaScript syntax and structure.

Comment: Are you trying to change the image on hover and revert back to the original when the cursor is no longer hovering over the link?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover

Comment: Guys! Thank you for both of you. I did something crazy, point me if I'm wrong. I have added data attribute method. What I did is actually added ```data-attribute```, then I set the ```data-attribute``` equal to number. Example in my HTML: ```data-pisti-product="0"```, ```data-pisti-product="1"```. Then i set all my ```<a>``` elements with same ```onmouseover="onHover(this)"```. Finally in my JavaScript I have added expression on my function called ```products``` then I set a ```var i = products.getAttribute("data-pisti-product")``` and using ```replace.src = array[i]```. Is this correct?

Comment: @tshimkus Yes, there are more than 10 ```<a>``` elements on the dropdown menu. Everyone item have different image and description.

Comment: @DipakDholakiya I cannot understand jQuery atm. But thanks anyway for the sharing.

Comment: A pure CSS solution might be available depending on how you will be populating the images. It would involve using the  [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class and a [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property. It may or may not be easier, depending on whether the images are relatively static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add parameter `n` to your function `onHover(n)`

```js
function onHover(n) {

    var pistiProducts = [
        "https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-1.jpg",
        "https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-2.jpg"
    ];

    var replace = document.getElementById("replacement");
    var itemdec = document.getElementById("text-replacement");

    replace.src = pistiProducts[n%2];
    itemdec.innerHTML = `Test ${n}`;

}
```

```css
img { height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu-wrapper d-flex">                                               
  <div class="dropdown-item-wrapper flex-grow-1">                                                
    <a id="pisti-products" onmouseover="onHover(0)" class="pisti-products" href="#">Action</a>                                                   
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(1)" href="#">Another action</a>                                                                                                       
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(2)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(3)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(4)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(5)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(6)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                         
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(7)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(8)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(9)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(10)" href="#">Something else here</a>                                                     
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(11)" href="#">Something else here</a>          
    
    <a class="" onmouseover="onHover(12)" href="#">Something else here</a> 
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown-display-wrapper">                                                     
    <div class="display-img replacement">                                                            
     <img id="replacement" class="w-100 img-fluid" src="https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/test-1.jpg" alt="">                                                       
    </div>                                                       
    <p class="mb-0 w-100 pisti-title" id="text-replacement">Another action</p>                                                   
  </div>                                                 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It work like charm. The description of the image I can use ```data-attribute``` right?