# Hover on images

Tags: image, hover

I have some images on website, and I want on hover to be next. Some color will appear, and some text also will appear. I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked for me. I want something like on this webiste http://corgan.ancorathemes.com/?fbclid=IwAR1sObu6Jhf2rMe4OBRZUPBE-KsLv98cBNpzaKxS-iT2MuJbd_mH7L5TeGc in part of site "What We Do". Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks to all.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I tried a lot of code, but like I said, nothing worked for me, and I deleted all this code which was not helpful for me, so I just have HTML code. If it could help you, I will post it

Comment: Have a look at this, seems like what you trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507870/jquery-image-changing-on-hover

Comment: Thanks on help, but unfortunately, it didn't help. I hope, it will be fixed on some way.